# How to auto upload the camera roll all photos to amazon s3 bucket like camera sync or dropbox doing

Tags: iphone, ios, amazon-s3

In my Iphone application I want to automatically upload the all photos to s3.

It run auto upload feature both in front and in background. When app is terminated, auto upload feature will also be stopped.

The way Dropbox and camera sync app doing.

Answer (score 0):

you should use "Finite-Length Task in the Background“. 
[Try this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios)
[And docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW28)

Comment: And off course uploading must be in not main thread. [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial)